# Процедурная генерация редактируемого цилиндра, подтяжка в развёртке. [Mesh > UV]

Tags: c#, 3d, unity3d, mesh

После процедурной генерации сетки, у меня, на объекте появляется подтяжка, хоть и я корректно генерировал развёртку. Если найдёте мою ошибку, пожалуйста опишите в чём она заключается. Я буду очень благодарен.

Генерация сетки:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PlasticBlock.Melting
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)), RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)), RequireComponent(typeof(UVWEditor)), ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class BodyGenerator : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Количество граней у тела.
        /// </summary>
        public int edges;      
        /// <summary>
        /// Количество генерируемых сегментов.
        /// </summary>
        public int heightSegments;
        /// <summary>
        /// Сегменты тела. Значения радиуса и высоты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2[] segments;
        /// <summary>
        /// Минимальные габариты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2 minRadius;
        /// <summary>
        /// Максимальные габариты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2 maxRadius;

        private UVWEditor _uvwEditor;
        private MeshRenderer _renderer;
        private MeshFilter _filter;
        private Mesh _mesh;
        private void Update()
        {
            Init();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Начало генерации процедурно генерируемой сетки.
        /// </summary>
        public void Init()
        {
            _renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            _filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            _uvwEditor = GetComponent<UVWEditor>();
            _mesh = new Mesh();
            _mesh.name = "Procedural Generated Object";
            _mesh.MarkDynamic();
            GenerateBody();
            _mesh = _uvwEditor.Calculate(_mesh, edges, heightSegments);
            _filter.mesh = _mesh;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Процедурная генерация сетки.
        /// </summary>
        private void GenerateBody()
        {
            int n = 0;
            _mesh.Clear();
            Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[edges * heightSegments];
            int[] links = new int[edges * heightSegments * 6 - 6];                      
            for (int m = 0, i = 0; i < heightSegments; i++)
            {
                for (float theta = 0; theta < 2 * Mathf.PI; theta += Mathf.PI * 2 / edges, m++)
                {
                    segments[i].x = segments[i].x >= minRadius.x ? segments[i].x : minRadius.x;
                    segments[i].x = segments[i].x <= maxRadius.x ? segments[i].x : maxRadius.x;
                    float y = segments[i].y + i * minRadius.y;
                    float x = segments[i].x * Mathf.Cos(theta);
                    float z = segments[i].x * Mathf.Sin(theta);
                    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);                  
                    vertices[m] = pos;
                    if (i == 1)
                        n++;
                }
            }
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < edges * (heightSegments - 1); i++)
            {
                int zeroPoint = i;
                int upperPoint = i + n;
                if ((i + 1) % edges == 0)
                {
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint - edges + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint - edges + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint - edges + 1; k++;
                }
                else
                {
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint + 1; k++;
                }
            }
            _mesh.vertices = vertices;
            _mesh.triangles = links;
            _mesh.Optimize();
            _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            _mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        }
    }
}
```

Генерация развёртки:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    namespace PlasticBlock.Melting
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Генератор развёртки.
        /// </summary>
        [ExecuteInEditMode]
        public class UVWEditor : MonoBehaviour
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Массив точек развёртки.
            /// </summary>
            public Vector2[] uvs;

            private int _edges, _heightSegments;
            private Mesh _mesh;
            private Texture2D _texture;

            /// <summary>
            /// Начало расчётов развёртки.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="mesh">Сетка.</param>
            /// <param name="edges">Количество краёв.</param>
            /// <param name="heightSegments">Количество сегментов.</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public Mesh Calculate(Mesh mesh, int edges, int heightSegments)
            {
                _mesh = mesh;
                _edges = edges;
                _heightSegments = heightSegments;
                CalculateUVWs();
                return _mesh;
            }
            private void CalculateUVWs()
            {
                uvs = new Vector2[_edges * _heightSegments];
                for (int y = 0; y < _heightSegments; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < _edges; x++)
                    {
                        float px = 1f / _edges * x;
                        float py = 1f / (_heightSegments - 1) * y;
                        uvs[y * _edges + x] = new Vector2(px,py);
                    }
                }
                _mesh.uv = uvs;
                _mesh.uv2 = uvs;
                _mesh.uv3 = uvs;
                _mesh.uv4 = uvs;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, сделанный из твоего

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PlasticBlock.Melting
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer)), RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)), RequireComponent(typeof(UVWEditor)), ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class BodyGenerator : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Количество граней у тела.
        /// </summary>
        public int edges;
        /// <summary>
        /// Количество генерируемых сегментов.
        /// </summary>
        public int heightSegments;
        /// <summary>
        /// Сегменты тела. Значения радиуса и высоты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2[] segments;
        /// <summary>
        /// Минимальные габариты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2 minRadius;
        /// <summary>
        /// Максимальные габариты сегмента.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2 maxRadius;

        private UVWEditor _uvwEditor;
        private MeshRenderer _renderer;
        private MeshFilter _filter;
        private Mesh _mesh;
        private void Update()
        {
            Init();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Начало генерации процедурно генерируемой сетки.
        /// </summary>
        public void Init()
        {
            _renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            _filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            _uvwEditor = GetComponent<UVWEditor>();
            _mesh = new Mesh();
            _mesh.name = "Procedural Generated Object";
            _mesh.MarkDynamic();
            GenerateBody();
            _mesh = _uvwEditor.Calculate(_mesh, edges, heightSegments);
            _filter.mesh = _mesh;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Процедурная генерация сетки.
        /// </summary>
        private void GenerateBody()
        {
            int n = 0;
            _mesh.Clear();
            Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(edges + 1) * heightSegments];
            int[] links = new int[edges * heightSegments * 6 - 6];
            for (int m = 0, i = 0; i < heightSegments; i++)
            {
                for (float theta = 0; theta < 2 * Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI * 2 / edges; theta += Mathf.PI * 2 / edges, m++)
                {
                    segments[i].x = segments[i].x >= minRadius.x ? segments[i].x : minRadius.x;
                    segments[i].x = segments[i].x <= maxRadius.x ? segments[i].x : maxRadius.x;
                    float y = segments[i].y + i * minRadius.y;
                    float x = segments[i].x * Mathf.Cos(theta);
                    float z = segments[i].x * Mathf.Sin(theta);
                    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                    vertices[m] = pos;
                    if (i == 1)
                        n++;
                }
            }
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < (edges + 1) * (heightSegments - 1); i++)
            {
                int zeroPoint = i;
                int upperPoint = i + edges + 1;
                if ((i + 1) % (edges + 1) == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint; k++;
                    links[k] = upperPoint + 1; k++;
                    links[k] = zeroPoint + 1; k++;
                }
            }
            _mesh.vertices = vertices;
            _mesh.triangles = links;
            _mesh.Optimize();
            _mesh.RecalculateNormals();
            _mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace PlasticBlock.Melting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Генератор развёртки.
    /// </summary>
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    public class UVWEditor : MonoBehaviour
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Массив точек развёртки.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector2[] uvs;

        private int _edges, _heightSegments;
        private Mesh _mesh;
        private Texture2D _texture;

        /// <summary>
        /// Начало расчётов развёртки.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mesh">Сетка.</param>
        /// <param name="edges">Количество краёв.</param>
        /// <param name="heightSegments">Количество сегментов.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Mesh Calculate(Mesh mesh, int edges, int heightSegments)
        {
            _mesh = mesh;
            _edges = edges;
            _heightSegments = heightSegments;
            CalculateUVWs();
            return _mesh;
        }
        private void CalculateUVWs()
        {
            uvs = new Vector2[(_edges + 1) * _heightSegments];
            for (int y = 0; y < _heightSegments; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < _edges + 1; x++)
                {
                    float px = 1f / _edges * x;
                    float py = 1f / (_heightSegments - 1) * y;
                    uvs[y * (_edges + 1) + x] = new Vector2(px, py);
                }
            }
            _mesh.uv = uvs;
            _mesh.uv2 = uvs;
            _mesh.uv3 = uvs;
            _mesh.uv4 = uvs;
        }
    }
}
```

Но честное слово, проще было написать заново. Вместо простых и понятных циклов по целым числам i,j у тебя то цикл по float (опасно), то сплошная нумерация, а потом выковыриваем j делением (нечитаемо).

Основная идея правки: я добавил еще один ряд точек, которые по координатам вершин совпадают с нулевым рядом, а по UV-координатам отличаются, дотягивая U до единицы, таким образом 0 дошел до 1, образовав шов.
http://take.ms/QwCSV